# Search same start of string with different end of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search a file with several strings that start with this 'table_name:'.  This string goes for a single line and can appear like any of these:

```
  table_name: one credit_ratings
  table_name: two abs
  table_name: three mbs
```

As you can see, the string starts the same and it can end in all kinds of characters.  I want to copy that line that contains 'table_name:' go down 8 lines and copy everything from there to 'id: validate' (this string is always the same).

I put the first string into this link (https://pythex.org/) and got the first part of the match working with:  `\stable_name:\s`  The problem is that I'm trying to match multiple characters, not a single character.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but the regex `' table_name:\s+[a-z _]+'` will find any of those table name sample strings you provided. You can use `' table_name:\s+([a-z _]+)'` (with the parenthesis) to make the value accessible via `.groups()`, as in `re.findall(r' table_name:\s+([a-z _]+)', lines).groups()`. Pythex has a helpful cheatsheet at the bottom of the page; it explains that `+` matches one or more characters.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where this config-type file is coming from? It looks almost like yaml and there could be much simpler (and less brittle) ways to parse it.

Comment: It's a standard YAML file, as far as I know.  I'm getting an error that reads: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace' when I read one file and it works perfectly fine when I read in another text file.  It's definitely less than ideal, but still far better than doing this all in Excel (which requires at least 10x more lines of code to do the same thing).

Comment: @ryguy72 https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/ ?

Comment: I installed the PyAML package and runa the code below: 'import yaml
with open('C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\\file_in.yaml') as f:
    # use safe_load instead load
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)'  Now, I get this error.  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.  I'm guessing this is some kind of non-standard yaml, and that's the problem, right.